# Where's the bottleneck? Not bad configuration, bad performance

Tags: performance, gaming, nvidia-geforce, intel-core-i7

I recently bought a new computer.

I have:

- Intel Core i7 3820 (not overclocked, so 3.6 GGHz) on a 2011 socket
- 2x4GiB Corsair DDR3 RAM (1866MHz) 1x8GB HyperX Fury DDR3 RAM (1866MHz)
- 1x nVidia GeForce 660 GTX 2GB
- 1x 256 GB SSD
- 1x 2 TB HDD (5400 RPM, Seagate Desktop HDD)

So, it's a sort of mid-performance low-budget machine, but it should run way better than it does.

System it's ok (Win10 Fast Ring builds) and works fine but when it cames to gaming...

I know I cant play Witcher 3 on high graphics but I have FPS drops also on Assassin's Creed Brotherhood at max graphics, sometimes also at mid graphics!

I optimized everything. I used Process Lasso Pro (very useful but didnt solve it all), updated drivers, very few processes in background...

I just can't understand why performances are so poor...

Comment: Have you disabled Xbox GameDVR?

Comment: nope, it will boost performances?

Comment: Normally helps, have a look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/4xu9vi/bad_fps_after_latest_win10_anniversary_update_got/

Comment: Also, I presume you have the latest nVidia graphics drivers from their website?

Comment: yep, I even installed the game ready drivers just in case it helped.
I'll try these steps, looks like it can be very useful trying that steps also because hardware load isnt high when playing (says Process Lasso) so maybe the bottleneck is in that crappy xbox app

Comment: replace the old 660GTx with a 1050Ti or 1060 to have perf boost. the 660 is from 2012, so a bit old

Comment: i know that, but my budget doesnt let me doing that ;)
i had to accept a 660gtx but AC:brotherhood is from 2010 (or 2011) so should work perfectly with a 660...thats why i asked about another bottleneck

Comment: the win10 v1703 has fps drops . wait for 1709 and look if this fixes it.

Comment: accurate! I just installed the insider build of 1709 and im at full fps with full graphics!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 Creators Update [1703/Build 15063 has fps drop issues](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-admits-to-gaming-performance-issues-in-windows-10-creators-update) which is fixed in the latest Windows 10 Insider Builds:

> Thank you everyone for providing feedback and submitting traces. We
>   have been analyzing the traces from your feedback and have identified
>   several different problem sources surfacing as stutter in games. **We
>   have a fix for one of them in the Windows Insider build that flighted
>   to the “Fast” ring (build 16273 and above).**

So update to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update v1709 to get those issues fixed or stay at Windows 10 v1607.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you can disable Game Mode.  Also the potential performance drop isn’t significant anyways.